# less of a trip and more of a mellow high

Tags: meaning

*Jesse Longo with Den of Geek rated it 2.5 out of 5 stars, commenting that "The episode was **less of a trip and more of a mellow high**.*

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hummels_%26_Heroin

Can you tell what is meant by the critical evaluation in bold. I think that it could mean that the episode was not a stunner but average but it stems from the stars that were given.

Comment: For me, it's hilarious to read serious critiques of a South Park episode. It's pretty common for movie and television critics to make humorous comparisons like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A **trip** is a hallucinogenic experience.  A **mellow high** is a milder altered state with a sense of well-being.

The terms are being used figuratively, of course, and subjectively, with **trip** being at the "best" end of the rating spectrum.

Comment: Worth noting, I think, is that both _trip_ and _high_ are common parlance within the drug culture.

Comment: You're  a trip, @J.R.  ;)